# Convert string to date with timezone

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

i have date string `2017-01-03T10:45:00.000+02:00` and I need to transfer it to something like this `2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200`

```
 let formatter = DateFormatter()
 formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
 // this formatter returning 2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000 but I need 
 // 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to change the timezone of data?

Comment: as long as `2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000` is equal to `2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200`, you might want specify what you actually looking for...

Comment: hope it helps u to better understand http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Comment: Yes, you are right 2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000 is 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200 but I need that date somehow to show me 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200 not 2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000 and if there will be 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0300 I need 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0300 not 2017-01-03 07:45:00 +0000. I have timeline in my project and I need to show time with that offsets.

Comment: This should do some trick: `let originalDateStr = "2017-01-03T10:45:00.000+02:00"; let formatter = DateFormatter(); formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"; let date = formatter.date(from: originalDateStr); let timeZone = NSTimeZone.init(forSecondsFromGMT: 2*3600); formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"; formatter.timeZone = timeZone as TimeZone!; let finalStr = formatter.string(from: date!); print("finalStr \(finalStr)");` It's missing how to retrieve 2*3600 from the string, but it's a start.

Comment: @Larme Please make your – correct – comment an answer. Lifeplus: You need two date formatters: one for converting the date string into a date and a second one to convert the date into the desired date string.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad You don't really needs two DateFormatter, but more two dateFormat, since you can reset the properties of the dateFormatter before using it a second time (like locale/timeZone). Also, the better solution and fastest may be to just replace the char in string (replace "T" with space, remove in NSRange(21,4) with space...

Comment: Yes, you can reconfigure the formatter every time, what is completely meaningless. Why should one do so? I do not think that replacing on string side is a good solution, because it does not take into account, that it isn't an ordinary string, but a date.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Well, since user seems only interested into the String representation, and the format has to be respected (which if not the case, would also disrupt the `NSDateFormatter` and return nil), it may be interesting. I read that the alloc/init of a `NSDateFormatter` was "heavy" (don't know how much), but keeping only one, or just none (only with string) may be more optimized.

Comment: You do not have to create a new instance every time. Simply create two lazy and hold it. You're done. That the OP is only interested in the string representation does not change the fact, that it is a date string. However, the OP did not mention problems with the runtime behavior. So optimizations are premature. I would write my solution as close to the problem as possible to make the code clear. "date" is a part of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

**Swift 3.0**

```
let dateStr = "2017-01-03T10:45:00.000+02:00"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'.000\'z"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)

print("Date from String : \(date)")

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxxx'"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 7200) as TimeZone!

print("String From Date : \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))")
```

**Result:**

Date from String : Optional(2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000)

String From Date : 2017-01-03 10:45:00 +0200

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me, Hope it help's you

```
 let dateString = "2017-01-03 08:45:00 +0000"

// create dateFormatter with UTC time format
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxxx"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)// create   date from string
print("Date1 : \(date)")
// change to a readable time format and change to local time zone
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss xxxx'"
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 7200) as TimeZone!
print("Date2 : \(dateFormatter.string(from: date!))")
```

Comment: Ok, question for all in this question: Why are you all using this `NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!` instead of using `TimeZone` initializer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert String to Date try the below code and let me know,

```
let dateString = "2016-10-25"
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let FormatDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(FormatDate)
```

More over you can get the time from below format:

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let dateString = "2017-01-03T10:45:00.000+02:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "UTC") as TimeZone!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss SSSZ"
let FormatDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
print(FormatDate)
```

Comment: This will return nil.