# Get NSDate object from server timestamp string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a server timestamp format like so `2016-11-21T11:04:02`, how can I convert this to an NSDate object?

Comment: What have you treid so far?

Comment: What is 21T11 ?

Comment: Looks like 21 is the date and T means 'time'. I don't recognise this format either.

Comment: Use DateFormatter or NSDateFormatter to convert string to NSDate

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238329/convert-string-to-date-with-timezone/40241269#40241269

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *serverTimeString=@"2016-11-21T11:04:02";

NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:serverTimeString];
```